# Implementation of ejudge on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I understand that this question may be not appropriate for stackoverflow's rules of asking a question, however I have no idea how to implement e-judge system on ASP.NET MVC5.

Let's define what I mean by "e-judge system" : it is a very simplified analogue of topcoder.com, codeforces.ru's code-checking system. User uploads some source file like a.cpp, b.cs, c.py or write code inside some form and submit it.

On server side I want my back-end to **run this code in some sandbox (in order to prevent hacking), compare outputs with the stored correct answers** and report the result to the user.

I have a problem with the bold-defined moment above. How can I run submissions (strings of code of source files) asynchronously in some sandbox? How should I collect an output and compare it with correct ones? The only idea I have is based on sending the submission via some message-broker to another application and waiting for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will give you a better answer, however because there isn't anything here at the moment my 2 cents:

- You could always use a virtualised machine to run your code.
- Use Windows Communication Foundation to send messages to/from the machine and run the software and get the responses. This could possibly be a Windows Service so it runs on startup or possibly just stick it in the startup folder (I think this runs on login).
- Run the code as a user that has limited rights on the machine, preventing hacks or at least limiting what the hacker can do.
- Have the machine in a standalone workgroup.
- Close all ports apart from the ones that WCF is using.
- You can take a snapshot of the machine and restore to that point if it does get broken for whatever reason.

This is a lot work so someone may come up with a much easier answer but I think this is as secure as you could get it. This solution might be using a hammer to crack a nut though and will take up considerable resources.